# how to read binary after resize image on python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

i use two packages
`from PIL import Image` and `from resizeimage import resizeimage` when i use this packages i should after resize save to other image file, but i need image binary after resize not save to other file ?

code :

```
with open(imgpath, 'r+b') as f:
    with Image.open(f) as image:
        cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, [100, 100])
             img =  bytearray(cover.read())
```

i need read binary like this : `bytearray(cover.read())` this code not work,
how to read binary after resize image?

Comment: Your method is `binary` but your variable not `binary` ! **`StringIO` ?**

Comment: please look answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use this code.

```
basewidth = 100
hsize =  100
img = Image.open(imgpath)
img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
byte_io = io.BytesIO()
img.save(byte_io, format='PNG')
byte_io = byte_io.getvalue()
print byte_io
```